# Bootstrap multiple standalone components

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components, angular17

I am working on an Angular 17 project, and I want to bootstrap multiple components directly in the main.ts file without using separate module files. However, my attempts have been unsuccessful, and I'm encountering issues with component initialization.

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { NavVerticalComponent } from './app/layout/navbar/nav-vertical/nav-vertical.component';
import { NavTopComponent } from './app/layout/navbar/nav-top/nav-top.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
   .then(appRef => {
       appRef.bootstrap(NavVerticalComponent);
       appRef.bootstrap(NavTopComponent)
   })
   .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Despite these efforts, I'm facing issues with the initialization of the components. The second component (NavTopComponent) doesn't seem to be included when both are specified in the bootstrap array.

Comment: Why not just include the other components in the `imports` of the AppComponent decorator? `@Component({selector: 'app-root', standalone: true, imports: [NavTopComponent, NavVerticalComponent])`

Comment: @BizzyBob I need to use three component in my index.html file if move my index.html content to app component the extra tag of angular so it’s ruin my style

Answer (score 3):

Actually, angular has multiple selectors for the root component, please find below an example where I changed the root component to the attribute selector `[appRoot]` then added it to the body tag, which generates an output without the root tag itself!

[Angular selector documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body appRoot></body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';
import { CComponent } from './c/c.component';

@Component({
  selector: '[appRoot]',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AComponent, BComponent, CComponent],
  template: `
    <app-a></app-a>
    <app-b></app-b>
    <app-c></app-c>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nx7jyt?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fc%2Fc.component.ts,src%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts,src%2Fa%2Fa.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I don't see what changing the selector has to do with the question.

Comment: @BizzyBob there is no root component to mess up the css

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `bootstrapApplication` is not designed to have multiple Angular App instances on the same page.

In order to achieve your result you can wrap your components with modules and run `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule()` for each one.